# How to send 2 dimensional Matrix with unknown size to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a 2 dimensional Matrix to a function

```
//function to print Matrix
void refl(int n, int board[][])
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {

            cout << board[i][j]  << "  ";
            }
        cout << endl; //printing the matrix to the screen
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    string refl;
    cin>>n;
    int board[n][n]; //creates a n*n matrix or a 2d array.

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
            cin>>board[i][j];
    refl(n , board);
    }

return 0;
}
```

It says that "n" and "board" isn't declared in the function while they are .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use C++ `std::vector` or good old C `malloc`+`free`.

C++

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void reflxx(int n, vector<vector<int>>& board)
{
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {

            cout << board[i][j]  << "  ";
            }
        cout << endl; //printing the matrix to the screen
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    string refl;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<int>> board(n, vector<int>(n));
     //creates a n*n matrix or a 2d array.

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)    //This loops on the rows.
    {
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) //This loops on the columns
            cin>>board[i][j];
    }
    reflxx(n , board);

return 0;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/ for more example.

Comment: I've tried your method
now I get this error:
    
`|29|error: no match for call to '(std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}) (int&, int [n][n])'|`
**specifically at this line of code**
 `refl(n , board);`

Comment: Ah, I should have try to compile this before posting, can't get it to work. Normally, if we want to create a dynamic array with variable size in runtime, we either use `malloc`+`free` or `std::vector`.

Comment: I'm asking for too much but can you tell me how to use std::vector ?
cuz I'm hearing about it alot.

Comment: Thanks John , 
I appreciate your help ^^
but when I run it,
the function only print the first row

Comment: You mean everytime finish typing one row of data, program prints the whole matrix (which means if n = 3, programs print 3x3 matrix 3 times)? You want to only print after all data is entered?

Comment: yes I want the program to print after finishing reading the matrix